# Magento Add fee on grand-total depending about payment gateway user selcted

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, observers

I need to add extra fee on grand-total and fee depend upon payment gateway user selected means if user select payment method 1 fee will be $3 and so on....I'm able to add fee on grand total with help of "sales_quote_collect_totals_after" observer.

Now I need to get current payment gateway so I will charge user according that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me get that straight – you are earning money with that and expect the community to be your free wageslave (nowageslave, if you will) and write the code you want to earn money with? That's bold, to say the least.

Comment: I'm not getting your point...i'm not earning any money with this code. i'm magento developer and creating extension.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg for your suggestion and i ll remember those point before adding any question in stack-flow in future.I solved my issue myself.

Comment: @vikasverma you should answer it